# VBA UDF to calculate Covariance from Daily Stock prices

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, covariance

Result Screenshot: ERROR:

[image: Result Screenshot: ERROR]

Sample data Screenshot:

[image: Sample data Screenshot]

I am new to VBA and right now I am stuck with an error. I want to calculate Covariance by taking stock prices as a parameter which returns a n*n array (n= number of columns of its parameter). I cannot figure out my mistake in the following code:

```
Function covarmat(prices As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    n = prices.Columns.Count

    Dim resultarray()

    ReDim resultarray(n, n)
    Dim f  'as a proxy for return variant
    Dim basicarray() 'to extract columns and calculate returns
    ReDim basicarray(prices.Rows.Count, prices.Columns.Count)                                               Tried this separately! Works perfect!

    For j = 1 To prices.Columns.Count
        For i = 1 To prices.Rows.Count
            basicarray(i, j) = prices(i + 1, j) / prices(i, j) - 1
        Next i
    Next j
    f = basicarray

    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To n
            resultarray(i, j) = Application.Covariance_S(f.columns(i), f.Columns(j))
        Next j
    Next i

covarmat = resultarray
End Function
```

Comment: Can you update the question with sample data/ screen shot? Also, dont we need two arrays for covariance calculation?Refer [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/covariance-p-function-6f0e1e6d-956d-4e4b-9943-cfef0bf9edfc)

Comment: @NareshBhople Yes indeed we require two arrays, my parameter selects a range and automatically calculates the Covar between two different columns from the given range! Have a look at the sample data link for screenshot for more clarity.

Comment: I tried the code .. The function returns value error.. can you add one more screen shot for the result you are getting? Also, have you tried covariance in data analysis addin? Yes it should return an array of n*n columns. As it calculates covariance of each column with every other column.

Comment: @NareshBhople There, I have added the result screenshot. I am getting the same error, obviously.  Data Analysis addin? I am sorry, I didn't get that part.

Comment: You can turn on the data analysis add in from excel add ins. Then you can use covariance tool. If you are trying to get something like correlation of stock prices with their index, you can try regression analysis in the data analysis add in. Therein you will get R-Square as well as P-Value

Comment: @NareshBhople My target is to make the UDF work as a part of my assignment. I cannot figure out the error in this code!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an array of the covarinace_s. So its an array formula. Select range equal to n*n and enter the formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter).

```
Function covarmat(prices As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    n = prices.Columns.Count

    Dim resultarray()
    ReDim resultarray(1 To n, 1 To n)

    Dim basicarray()
    ReDim basicarray(1 To prices.Rows.Count - 1, 1 To n)

    For j = 1 To n
        For i = 1 To prices.Rows.Count - 1
            basicarray(i, j) = prices(i + 1, j) / prices(i, j) - 1
        Next i
    Next j

    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To n
            resultarray(i, j) = Application.Covariance_S _
            (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(basicarray, 0, i), _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(basicarray, 0, j))
        Next j
    Next i

covarmat = resultarray
End Function
```

Comment: Prices parameter is for the stock prices and not daily returns on the stock. Covariance is to be calculated from the daily stock returns and not prices. That is why I added the proxy and additional temporary array.

Comment: The answer is almost correct. The result I was getting was different the right values. Thank you for the help!

Comment: My Bad! Your code is totally correct! 100% right. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If this answers your question, please upvote/ accept/ Tick the answer to close the question